# It it possible to fit a detachable tow bar to a BMW 335D M Sport Touring (F31/2016) in a way that does not need a bumper cut

Tags: bmw, towing

I have a lease BMW 335D M Sport Touring (F31/2016) and I am not permitted to alter it without reparing any changes.
So, if I fit a tow bar I have to remove it at the end of the lease.

I've asked various dealers and I get conflicting answers.  Having to replace the bumper would be a costly extra.

Can it be done in a way that definately does not need a bumper cut?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Sorry to have to close your question, but shopping questions really don't fit in with the site.

Comment: This is not a shopping question, rather a question for a person perhaps involved in the tow bar industry who has experience of all of the possible products.  They might answer "No, the design of the car means you have to cut the bumper"

Comment: Asking for a product which meets your needs is a shopping question. If you believe I'm in error, please go through the re-open process. If the community feels otherwise, I'm happy to allow it back open.

Comment: If you think there is a better way of asking if it's possible to fit a tow bar without altering the fabric of the car then I'm happy to take your advice.  I will alter the title of the question to remove the word 'available'.  BTW: I'm no noob to SE.

Comment: You could always bring the question to [The Pitstop](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop) ... as you most likely know, the SE chatrooms are a lot more freeform and broader in scope. We can most likely discuss it there without issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've reviewed installer diagrams for many towbar manufacturers (as far as I can tell all of them) and found only TWO that do not need a bumper cut on this vehicle IF the vehicle is not fitted with an rear undertray (which can be removed anyway).

Solution 1: BMW do a retro fittable factory kit but it's VERY expensive.
Solution 2: A UK company, PCT do a kit (BM6135A) that is more sensibly priced.